# Can you 'pull' the terms and conditions from magento and use on a seprate page in magento

Tags: php, magento

i need to use the same text i put in my terms of service in magento but i need the same text to appear on a seperate lightbox page. is there a way i can 'pull' that text to my site without actually having 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data of a page using it's identifier...

> > echo Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('terms-and-conditions', 'identifier')->getContent();

Comment: is it possible to use this code through a magento page?